# Using PHP and MySQL encode/decode returns only few characters of result

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, rackspace-cloud

so this problem may be caused one of many things. Here's my situation.

I'm using an ec2 server as my host website which connects to a rackspace database through a rackspace load balancer (they don't allow connections to databases from sources outside rackspace).

Anyway, my problem is that I'm trying to encode my mysql table on insertion and decode it on selection. Here's the code I use to make insertions:

```
function mysql_insert_sanitize_encrypt_store($databaseName,$names,$values,$link){
$query="INSERT INTO ".$databaseName." (";
foreach($names as $name){
$query=$query.$name.",";
}
$query[strlen($query)-1]=")"; //replace trailing comma with parenthesis 
$query=$query." VALUES (";
foreach($values as $value){
$sanivalue=filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$query=$query."ENCODE('".$sanivalue."','encryptionstring'),";
}
$query[strlen($query)-1]=")";
echo $query;
if(mysql_query($query,$link)){
return 1;
}
}
```

which generates a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO PublishedItems (PublisherUrl,Age,option,experience,goals,gender,minstaken,Item) VALUES (ENCODE('https://www.google.com/profiles/100571329423938175195','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('18-30,30-45','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('15-30','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('novice,amateur','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('Loseweight','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('male','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('120','encryptionstring'),ENCODE('[[{"name":"MW350","value":""},{"name":"MD350","value":""}]]','encryptionstring'))
```

and this returns as a successful insertion.

When I try to get the data again, I use the following code:

```
$query="select ".$decryptionQueries[$count++]." FROM ".$DBName;
mysql_free_result($result);
$result=mysql_query($query,$link);
echo "</br>";
echo $query;
echo "</br>";
echo "decrypted result --->";
var_dump($result);
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>============".$DBName."============UNENCRYPTED=========</br>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "</br>";
var_dump($row);
echo "</br>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(),true) . "</pre>";
}
```

where decryption queries are defined as follows:

$`decryptionQueries=array("DECODE(PublisherUrl, 'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Age,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(option,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(experience,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(goals,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(gender,'encryptionstring'),DECODE(minstaken,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Item,'encryptionstring')","DECODE(User,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Age,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(option,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(experience,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(goals,'encryptionstring'),DECODE(gender,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Injuries,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(availperday,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Item,'encryptionstring')");`

and this generates queries like this:

```
select DECODE(PublisherUrl, 'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Age,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(option,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(experience,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(goals,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(gender,'encryptionstring'),DECODE(minstaken,'encryptionstring'), DECODE(Item,'encryptionstring') FROM PublishedItems
```

But when displaying the data, the defined variables entry for the rows variable reads as follows:

```
[row] => Array
        (
            [0] => h
            [DECODE(PublisherUrl, 'encryptionstring')] => h
            [1] => 18-3
            [DECODE(Age,'encryptionstring')] => 18-3
            [2] => 15-3
            [DECODE(option,'encryptionstring')] => 15-3
            [3] => 
            [DECODE(experience,'encryptionstring')] => 
            [4] => 
            [DECODE(goals,'encryptionstring')] => 
            [5] => male
            [DECODE(gender,'encryptionstring')] => male
            [6] => 1
            [DECODE(minstaken,'encryptionstring')] => 1
            [7] => [
            [DECODE(Item,'encryptionstring')] => [
```

My question is: Why does this return only parts of the string stored in the database? Or why would it only store part of the string? What is going wrong with my code? Is it something to do with encode and decode?

When the input is not encoded first and just selected from the database it returns correctly and completely, so I'm thinking it has something to do with encoding and decoding.

What do you think is the problem?

EDIT:

Iterating through the rows of one of the tables gives the following output (I just var_dumped the row)

```
============PublishedItems============ENCRYPTED=========

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(1) "A" ["Age"]=> string(3) "7b?" ["option"]=> string(3) "7C?" ["experience"]=> string(0) "" ["goals"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(4) " ¬'" ["minsTaken"]=> string(1) "7" ["Item"]=> string(1) "-" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 21:05:57" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(1) "A" ["Age"]=> string(3) "7b?" ["option"]=> string(3) "7C?" ["experience"]=> string(0) "" ["goals"]=> string(1) " " ["gender"]=> string(5) " ¬'#" ["minsTaken"]=> string(1) "7" ["Item"]=> string(1) "-" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 21:10:41" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(1) "A" ["Age"]=> string(3) "7b?" ["option"]=> string(3) "7C?" ["experience"]=> string(0) "" ["goals"]=> string(1) " " ["gender"]=> string(5) " ¬'#" ["minsTaken"]=> string(1) "0" ["Item"]=> string(1) "-" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 21:16:55" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(1) "A" ["Age"]=> string(3) "7b?" ["option"]=> string(3) "7C?" ["experience"]=> string(0) "" ["goals"]=> string(1) " " ["gender"]=> string(4) " ¬'" ["minsTaken"]=> string(1) "7" ["Item"]=> string(1) "-" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 22:34:14" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(53) "https://www.google.com/profiles/100571329423938175195" ["Age"]=> string(3) "45+" ["option"]=> string(7) "below15" ["experience"]=> string(6) "novice" ["goals"]=> string(10) "Loseweight" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["minsTaken"]=> string(3) "120" ["Item"]=> string(59) "[[{"name":"MW484","value":""},{"name":"MD484","value":""}]]" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 22:49:41" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(53) "https://www.google.com/profiles/100571329423938175195" ["Age"]=> string(3) "45+" ["option"]=> string(8) "below15," ["experience"]=> string(6) "novice" ["goals"]=> string(10) "Loseweight" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["minsTaken"]=> string(3) "120" ["Item"]=> string(117) "[[{"name":"MW310","value":""},{"name":"MD310","value":""}],[{"name":"MW900","value":""},{"name":"MD900","value":""}]]" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 22:50:19" } 

array(9) { ["PublisherUrl"]=> string(1) "A" ["Age"]=> string(2) "vS" ["option"]=> string(0) "" ["experience"]=> string(0) "" ["goals"]=> string(0) "" ["gender"]=> string(4) " ¬'" ["minsTaken"]=> string(1) "7" ["Item"]=> string(1) "-" ["DateSubmitted"]=> string(19) "2012-09-14 23:50:32" }
```

Notice that some of the string were not encrypted, I did this as a control, which suggests that it's the encoding insertion that is the problem, but I can't think of how the query string for insertion (see the 2nd code snippet) would only insert part of the message. Decrypted, these strings give partial string that, if whole, would be correct.

Additionally, here is the declaration of the table:

```
create table PublishedItemss (PublisherUrl char(150),Age char(5),option char(8),experience char(20), goals char(50), gender char(8), minsTaken int, item TEXT,DateSubmitted timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW())';
```

Comment: Is the data added to your database properly?

Comment: I am pretty sure, the result of the mysql insertion query is bool(true)

Comment: Sorry, I meant is the right information going in there - check the database to see if it's the full, encoded strings that have been added or if they've been truncated.

Comment: I can't get terminal access so I can't be positive (long story) but I when I var_dump the row it gives me only part of the encoded string. I will add it to an edit for my question